# torch matrix equaity sum operation

Tags: pytorch, array-broadcasting

I want to do an operation similar to matrix multiplication, except instead of multiplying I want to check equality. The effect that I want to achieve is similar to the following:

```py
a = torch.Tensor([[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]]).to(torch.uint8)
b = torch.Tensor([[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]).to(torch.uint8)
result = [[sum(a[i] == b [j]) for j in range(len(b))] for i in range(len(a))]
```

Is there a way that I can use einsum, or any other function in pytorch to achieve the above efficiently?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make use of the [broadcasting](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/notes/broadcasting.html) to do the same, for instance with

```
result = (a[:, None, :] == b[None, :, :]).sum(dim=2)
```

Here `None` just introduces a dummy dimensions - alternatively you can use the less visual `.unsqueeze()` instead.

Comment: You can do `(a[:, None] == b[None]).sum(dim=2)`... trailing semicolons are not necessary ;).

Comment: @Ivan Thanks for adding that, that is true! And as it is just a leading dummy dimension we could also just write `b` instead - I just tried to make it as visually explicit as possible in case someone has not seen this notation before:)

Comment: Good point! I didn't notice you could actually do it with `b` directly (w/o additional dims).

Comment: Is there any advantage of using view instead of using None (which I imagine is using reshape underneath).

Comment: I think all these are pretty much equivalent and quite efficient, as they only deal with the strides of the given array. If in doubt I'd consider doing an experiment with e.g. `timeit`.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [torch.repeat](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.Tensor.repeat.html#torch.Tensor.repeat) and [torch.repeat_interleave](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.repeat_interleave.html#torch.repeat_interleave):

```
a = torch.Tensor([[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]])
b = torch.Tensor([[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]])

mask = a.repeat_interleave(3, dim=0) == b.repeat((2, 1))

torch.sum(mask, axis=1).reshape(a.shape)

# output
tensor([[3, 0, 0],
        [0, 3, 0]])
```

Comment: Do you know if the memory consumption is higher than the `unsqueeze()` answer? In my case I have large matrices (a is 1000000 x 48 and b is 1000 x 48). I'm worried that `repeat_interleave` would need repeated memory?

Comment: There is a bug in your code I think. `b.repeat` does not take in a `dim` argument.

Answer (score 1):

matrix multiplication is `ij,jk->ik` in einsum notation, all of these operations are equivalent with varying levels of verbosity:

```
a @ b
torch.einsum("ij,jk", a, b)
torch.einsum("ij,jk->ik", a, b)
(a[:,:,None] * b[None,:,:]).sum(1)
```

"multiply `i` and `k` dimensions and reduce `j` dimension"

```
    i, j, k             i,    j, k
a: (2, 3)        =>    (2,    3, None)
b:    (3, 3)           (None, 3, 3)
```

It should now be clear from this function decomposition that multiplication can be replaced with any binary operation, e.g. the equality operation.

Unfortunately, there is no generalized form of einsum (AFAIK) in pytorch that swaps the multiplication  "out-of-the-box". There is however the [`einops`](https://github.com/arogozhnikov/einops) library which is basically a wrapper around deep learning frameworks such as PyTorch.